# Why is my SQL statement so slow (sqlite 3)?

Tags: python, sql, performance, sqlite

So I'm using python sqlite3 to connect to a locally saved database on my laptop and query tables.
The tables are fairly large and have up to 5 million rows (minutely forex exchange rates).

I have 3 relevant tables in the database ("EURUSD", "BTCUSD", "ETHUSD") each with the columns "Timestamp" and "Open", which corresponds to the rate at a specific minute (the format is [Unix Timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php).

I have another table in python whick looks like this:
[Table to be filled with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxcfH.png)

What I'm trying to do is the following:
For every row in the table to be filled: Check the currency and search for the NEAREST timestamp value in the database and return the corresponding "Open". So if the currency in the table is "EUR". Go to the table "EURUSD", select the nearest timestamp and return the open rate. If the currency is "BTC", go to the table "BTCUSD", select the nearest timestamp and return the open.

It has to be the nearest timestamp since the exact timestamp may not be in the database.

My current code looks like this, but I'm iterating over this code 100's of times for every row and this makes it slow.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(path)
cur = conn.cursor()
for idx in dataframe.index:
  timestamp = dataframe.loc[idx, "Timestamp"]
  cur.execute("SELECT TimestampUnix, Open FROM EURUSD WHERE EURUSD.TimestampUnix< "+str(timestamp)
  ORDER BY EURUSD.TimestampUnix DESC LIMIT 1"
  query = cur.fetchall()
  rate = query[0][1]
  dataframe.loc[idx, "ForexRate"] = rate
```

I indexed the table on "TimestampUnix" which dropped the runtime for one query from 5s down to 1s. But still, it seems to long for a locally executed query.

My thought was that the SQL query could be the problem since it selects nearly the whole table in some cases and has to order it.
Do you have any other ideas to make it faster?

EDIT: I edited the description of what I want to do. I think (as some of you already mentionend) my solution is completely inefficient and maybe this could be solved with a single query. The query should essentially do two things:

- Select the right table to search in
- Find the nearest timestamp and return the corresponding open

Since I'm not proficient in SQL I'm having trouble with this and would appreciate the help.

Comment: Usually, simple SQL queries like this can be slow down by WHERE clauses when there is no index on the filtered column, SELECT on specific column names is goog practice too.

Comment: I have an index on the column TimestampUnix which is the filtered column in the WHERE clause. What do you mean by SELECT on specific column names? Does it look different than my code?

Comment: Open the database in the sqlite3 command line shell and use the [`.expert` command](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#index_recommendations_sqlite_expert_) to see if there's a better index you could add (might need a descending one)

Comment: You could also update your question to include the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN ...` output while you're doing that.

Comment: Finally, bind the timestamp value you're looking for to a parameter in the query instead of building a new query string each time. https://bobby-tables.com/python

Comment: and finally, finally, if you could provide the complete logic behind executing the query 100's of times, instead of once, with detail about which rows you wish to see in the result, that would be helpful.  It's quite possible you can do what you want in one query, returning the 100's of rows with this one query.

Comment: Actually there is no inherent logic to calling the query many times. How would a query have to look like to return all relevant relevant results at once, given a list or an array of say 100 timestamps?

Comment: We could generate that list of timestamps, if the requirement allows, then calculate the 1 row per timestamp dynamically within one query.  I don't have enough detail from the question, but I can show you one possible form.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated response based on new detail in the question.  The application based table can be inserted in the database before performing the following, or the data could, if necessary, be injected via a CTE term.

The test case:

[Working test case for sqlite](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=40275af0a1d7c43694f3ebfeef9f9c85)

The SQL of interest, first just the `SELECT` to generate a result the application could then use to update local data, followed by an example which updates a target table created in the database which contains the application data to be populated with new Open/rate data.

The literal `3000000000` is just the timestamp delta / range over which we search for `Open` detail from the provided application timestamp of interest, for each row provided by the application.  Basically, we find the nearest prior timestamp from the `EURUSD` table.

```
-- Just calculate the result, without touching target
WITH RECURSIVE ts (ts, n) AS (
         SELECT TimestampUnix, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TimestampUnix)
           FROM target WHERE currency = 'EUR'
     )
   , xrows (ts, n, TimestampUnix, Open, rn) AS (
         SELECT ts, n, EURUSD.TimestampUnix, EURUSD.Open
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n ORDER BY TimestampUnix DESC)
           FROM ts
           JOIN EURUSD
             ON EURUSD.TimestampUnix <=  ts.ts
            AND EURUSD.TimestampUnix >   ts.ts - 3000000000
     )
SELECT *
  FROM xrows WHERE rn = 1
;
```

```
-- Now use the above to UPDATE the target table.
-- sqlite might not support a JOIN here.
-- So we use correlated behavior in the SET clause

UPDATE target
   SET rate = (
            WITH ts (ts, n, currency) AS (
                     SELECT TimestampUnix, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TimestampUnix)
                          , currency
                       FROM target WHERE currency = 'EUR'
                 )
               , xrows (ts, n, currency, TimestampUnix, Open, rn) AS (
                     SELECT ts, n, currency, EURUSD.TimestampUnix, EURUSD.Open
                          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n ORDER BY TimestampUnix DESC)
                       FROM ts
                       JOIN EURUSD
                         ON EURUSD.TimestampUnix <=  ts.ts
                        AND EURUSD.TimestampUnix >   ts.ts - 3000000000
                 )
            SELECT Open
              FROM xrows
             WHERE rn = 1
               AND ts       = target.TimestampUnix
               AND currency = target.currency
       )
 WHERE currency = 'EUR'
;
```

The `eurusd` table and some generated sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE eurusd (
     TimestampUnix  timestamp, Open  int
);

-- Add some sample data for testing...
INSERT INTO eurusd
WITH RECURSIVE cte (ts, Open, n) AS (
        SELECT 1630942385000, 1101, 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT ts-1000000000, Open-1, n+1 FROM cte
         WHERE n < 15
     )
SELECT ts, Open FROM cte
;
```

The data generated looks like this:

[image]

The target / application table:

```
-- Let this table represent the data in the application to be updated.
CREATE TABLE target (
     TimestampUnix  timestamp
   , currency       varchar(10)
   , rate           int
);

-- The application could insert these rows before processing, or just provide this
-- data via a CTE term.
INSERT INTO target VALUES
    (1630942385000, 'TST',    0)
  , (1630942377000, 'EUR', NULL)
  , (1630942162000, 'BTC', NULL)
  , (1625942399000, 'EUR', NULL)
;
```

This table looks like this.  We expect to update the highlighted rows:

[image]

The result of the first query, which just shows the generated rows with the closest `rate` found:

[image]

The result of the `target` table after the `UPDATE`, with updated `rates` highlighted:

[image]

Original response:
Here's one way to calculate the timestamps of interest (every -12 hours starting with the current_timestamp) and then return 1 row per timestamp, based on the logic in the question.

We start with the current_timestamp - 12 hours and iteratively (via recursion) produce successive timestamp values from which to calculate the next result, until some stop condition.  I've added a condition to limit the number of iterations to about 10, but there is data only for a couple of days, which is 4 x 12 hour ranges.

`ROW_NUMBER` is used to calculate the position of each EURUSD row within each timestamp range (descending), so that rn = 1 represents that most recent row in the range, similar to your `ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT 1`.

I also adjusted your logic to avoid searching all data prior to the given timestamp.  If this contains months or years of data, it's likely you only need to review the last day or so, to get that most recent `Open` value per timestamp.  If that is acceptable, this could help your current SQL too.

It's also likely you'll get more significant improvement by just not iterating over your SQL 100's of times.

**Updated with a slightly better form:**

```
WITH RECURSIVE ts (ts, n) AS (
         SELECT datetime(current_timestamp, '-12 hour'), 1
          UNION ALL
         SELECT datetime(ts, '-12 hour'), n+1
           FROM ts
          WHERE n < 10
     )
   , xrows (ts, n, TimestampUnix, Open, rn) AS (
         SELECT ts, n, EURUSD.TimestampUnix, EURUSD.Open
              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n ORDER BY TimestampUnix DESC)
           FROM ts
           JOIN EURUSD
             ON EURUSD.TimestampUnix <  datetime(ts.ts, '+12 hour')
            AND EURUSD.TimestampUnix >= ts.ts
     )
SELECT *
  FROM xrows WHERE rn = 1
;
```

This is just an example.  The following fiddle contains some data for testing:

[Working Test Case with data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5ee1b30a2514872e7b006690720ff629)

Data used:

[image]

Result based on that data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I edited my question and gave more context to what I want to do since you correctly mentioned that it's the iteration over the query is what makes it slow.

Comment: @Pat396 This is even better, since we have the list of timestamps of interest in the database.  Now the question is, do you have some range over which the nearest timestamp will be found?  For instance, should we be able to find a `ts` within the prior day or week?  Any restriction could help the overall performance quite a bit.  Could we limit the timestamps from the table to be updated to just those which currently contain `NULL`?

Comment: @Pat396 Oh. "table in python" ... You could insert that table in the database (then update it) or add that table to the SQL (derived or as a CTE term).  Either would likely be better than iterating over the python list for each item separately.

Comment: Most of the time the nearest timestamp will be only minutes away. But there could be edge cases of up to 5 days. Also the query could be limited to update just those rows which currently contain NULL. 

Yes I was also thinking about inserting the table into the database, then updating it and returning it back to python for further processing, so this would be possible.

Comment: @Pat396 I've got a little test case coming, using raw timestamps (integer values) to avoid any date conversion complications in the example.  This could be done for all currency types at once.  But I'll focus on just the 'EUR' case for now.